# Display different set of buttons for different instances of tiny mce

Tags: tinymce

I'm adding text area dynamically, which will be instance of tine mce. In a page, I will be adding text area for say heading, paragraph etc. For heading, I need to have only b,I,U and align buttons displayed, also for p, I need a different set of buttons.
Is it possible ?
How to do if possible ?

Answer (score 0):

As far as i can see you want to have different instances of tinymce on a page.
All you need to do is to initialize each tinymce instance [with an own configuration](http://wiki.moxiecode.com/index.php/TinyMCE:Configuration).
you can